# Unity Animation won't play if not enough time since last animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, midi

I'm making a MIDI visualizer, and the first instrument I decided to try was the cowbell. Just to start, I'm storing a list of times of when the cowbell should play (I'll get to MIDI parsing later). It then checks if the current time is past or equal to the time of when the note should play.

```
for (int i = 0; i < times.Length; i++) { // For each note
         bool notePlayed = false;
         while (!notePlayed) { // While current note hasn't been played (waiting for its time)
             if (Time.timeSinceLevelLoad >= timesAdjusted [i]) { // If the current time is past or equal to the time it should play
                 anim.Play ("hit"); // Play animation
                 Debug.Log ("hit!");
                 notePlayed = true; // The note has been played.
             }
             yield return null;
         }
     }
```

This works, but only if the time between the previous note and the current note is big enough for the animation to finish. So, how can I get the animation to play regardless of whether or not the animation has finished?
[image]
[image]

Comment: So my issue was unrelated. In my code, I forgot to make sure some numbers for time calculations were casted to float, so basically all my note times were quantized to the quarter note. Many hours wasted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using "Play" method which will play an animation state regardless of your transition (Idle->Hit) , plus there's no condition defined in your transitions which will create an infinite loop between your states.

To resolve your main issue, you have to use set "normalizedTime" parameter to 0, like:

```
anim.Play ("hit",0,0); //assuming "hit" state is in your 0 layer
```

Comment: Just got back to doing this and ran into the same issue. This worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Disable has exit time  checkbox to change animation without waiting another